# How to improve performance of nested loops in javascript array manipulation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, big-o

I did a coding challenge requiring to merge an input of arrays into a new array by adding only once the duplicated elements and keeping the order of the array elements. My solution is below:

```
function union(arr){
 let newArr = [];
 let length = arr.length;
 for(let i=0; i< length; i++){
   for(let j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
   if(!newArr.includes(arr[i][j])){
     newArr.push(arr[i][j]);
   }
  }
 }
 return newArr;
```

I wanted to know how can I improve the big O performance of the above solution without using any javascript build in methods as reduce or map etc. Is there a way without using nested loops?

Comment: Maybe a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First flat with arrays flat method, then create a Set from the flatted array which will remove duplicates. And you have done in O(n) and two lines of code

Comment: @quirimmo can you elaborate more on the flatted array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're allowed to, I'd suggest adding all arrays to a `Set` (duplicate items will be ignored), and then turning the set back into an array:

```js
function union(input){
  const set = new Set(input.flat());
  return [...set];
}

console.log(union([[2, 3], [3, 4]]));
```

If computational complexity is an issue, it's often a good idea to use sets instead of arrays - `Array.prototype.includes` is `O(N)`, for example, while `Set.prototype.has` is `O(1)`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to do :) I thought the question was closed and I just dropped a comment instead of an answer